# PHP sending data to another page using session and form

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables, calculator

So im learning PHP and ive been trying to do some basic stuff with it.
ive been trying to make simple calculator with three different php pages.
First page takes 2 number values. On second page you choose what calculation you want to commit (its only value1 + value2 now) and third page is just printing the result. 
So this is super simple PHP stuff and i got it work many different ways, but when i try to use session on it i cant get it work. It looks like that on first page i cant get values on my session variable and i dont know how to fix this.
So i would be very greatful if someone would tell me how to make this work with session. I have exam coming soon about php and it would be nice to know how this works.

My First php page code:

```
session_start();

create_form();
send_values();

function create_form()
{    
?>
<form action="testilasku.php" method="get">

    <input type="text" name="value1">
    <input type="text" name="value2">
    <input type="submit" name="count">

</form>

<?php
}
function send_values()
{


if (!isset($_GET["count"]))
{

    $_SESSION["value1"] = $_GET["value1"];
    $_SESSION["value2"] = $_GET["value2"];
}
}
?>
```

My second php page code:

```
session_start();

$result = 0;
$value1 = 0;
$value2 = 0;



//$_SESSION["arvo5"] = $_GET["arvo1"];
//$_SESSION["arvo6"] = $_GET["arvo2"];

$value1 = $_SESSION["arvo5"];
$value2 = $_SESSION["arvo6"];

laskin($value1,$value2,$result);
set_values($result);
create_form();

echo $value1;
echo $value2;
echo $result;
function set_values($result)
{
    $_SESSION["result"] = $result;
}

function create_form()
{ 
?>
<form method="get" action="tulostin.php">
<input name="result" type="submit">
</form>

<?php
}
function laskin($value1,$value2,&$result)
{
    $result = $value1 + $value2;
}
?>
<a href="testilaskin.php">Go Back</a>
```

My third page:

```
<?php
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
echo $_SESSION["result"];
?>
```

Comment: Your first two pages don't have `<?php` tags at the beginning

Comment: why do you have different sessions? I mean: first write something into `$_SESSION["value1"]` and then get something from `$_SESSION["arvo5"]` (confusedFace). Your code is very hard to understand

Comment: It would also help to know what your "first page" "second page" and "third page" are called, so we can follow where your forms get sent. Currently, we have no way of following the flow when looking at the actual code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you can see in the `action` attributes of the forms the names of the pages. They are `testilaskin.php`, `testilasku.php` and `tulostin.php`.

Comment: You need to fetch the data from the form on the page you have in your `action`, not on the same page as the form itself. You also need to use the same session names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not receiving the data in the second page. You're tring to get the data of the first page's form (`value1` and `value2`) in the first page itself, using your function `send_values`, but that doesn't make much sense because the data is sent to the second page. In your second page you get the values like this:

```
$_SESSION["arvo5"] = $_GET["value1"];
$_SESSION["arvo6"] = $_GET["value2"];

$value1 = $_SESSION["arvo5"];
$value2 = $_SESSION["arvo6"];
```

That way you set the form values to the `SESSION` array and to the other variables.

If you want the numbers to be kept in your first page (because you have a back button in the second page), your first page would look like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

create_form();

function create_form() {
    // Here we get the values only if they are set.
    $value1 = isset($_SESSION['arvo5']) ? $_SESSION['arvo5'] : '';
    $value2 = isset($_SESSION['arvo6']) ? $_SESSION['arvo6'] : '';
?>
<form action="testilasku.php" method="get">

    <input type="text" name="value1" value="<?= $value1 ?>">
    <input type="text" name="value2" value="<?= $value2 ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="count">

</form>
<?php
}
```

---

Your logic should be simple:

Page1 shows form where user inputs numbers. The form will send the data to page 2. You don't use SESSION or GET here.

Page2 receives the numbers that are in the GET array, saves them to SESSION, and shows a form with a select input with the available operations (sum, sub, mult, etc). The form will send the data to page 3.

Page3 takes the selected operation and, in this case you should do a switch, like:

```
switch($_GET['operation']) {
    case '+':
        $result = $_SESSION['value1'] + $_SESSION['value2'];
        break;

    case '-':
        $result = $_SESSION['value1'] - $_SESSION['value2'];
        break;

    // etc...
}
```

And finally echoes `$result`.

Sorry for going beyond the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly where is failing, but you can try these:

- Swap the order of function calls in the first.php so your setting`$_SESSION` before any HTML.

  ```
  send_values();
  create_form();
  ```
- You're saving into `$_SESSION[value1]` in first.php but read out of `$_SESSION[arvo5]` in second.php
- Use `var_dump($_SESSION)` to debug your session variables

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try it but sadly it didn't work.